# Running sqlcmd from php

Tags: php, sql, sqlcmd

I have a pretty complicated bunch of sql calls that I have stored to a .sql file, that I can't call using sqlsrv_query because there are a bunch of GOs.

From the (windows) command line I can run the sql file using

```
"path\to\sqlcmd" -U name -P pass -S loc -i "path\to\stuff.sql"
```

I can also write system( [all that] ) in a php file that I run from the command line using `php -f`.

However, if I call the same system( [allthat] ) from a php file that I call using ajax on a website, I get no feedback, the sql just doesn't run.  I've checked sqlcmd, and it has permissions to allow all users to execute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions issue. If you're running it from the command line, it's running under YOUR permissions. When you invoke it via a webserver, it's running with the webserver's permisisons. The webserver will need execute rights (and permission to REACH the sqlcmd) as well as read rights on the .sql file (and permission to reach it).

Comment: That's what I assumed too, but the the "users" group has exec privileges- where else should I look?

Comment: More info: I ran system( 'mkdir path\to\sqlcmd\garbage' ), and the directory was made, so I *think* I have permission to reach sqlcmd.

Comment: What about the .sql file itself?

Comment: yeah, the php call actually writes the .sql file-  it reads a template, replaces a placeholder word with something else, writes the file to something new, and then passes that new file (after first closing it of course).  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like it's a User Account Control problem... I logged in as the webuser and tried to run from the cmd prompt, and had to authorize with an admin account.  Can you disable the UAC for this?  I have the "run as administrator" box checked for all users

Answer (score 0):

For that, you may use the [shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: that seems to have the same behavior as exec and system